# How to better handle long item names in CommandBar

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Is there a better way than the default to handle `CommandBar` items that have long text. The character length varies a lot by language and so at times it can be impossible to see what the item text is because of the wat the `CommandBar` changes when expanded.

**XAML (French)**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CommandBar Grid.Row="0">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <Button 
                Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" 
                Name="BackButton" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Click="Back_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>

        <AppBarButton Icon="Mail" Label="Information sur le produit"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Mail" Label="Avis sur les produits"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Mail" Label="Informations de contact"/>
    </CommandBar>
    <Frame Name="MyFrame" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

**XAML (Englsh)**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CommandBar Grid.Row="0">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <Button 
                Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" 
                Name="BackButton" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Click="Back_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>

        <AppBarButton Icon="Mail" Label="Product information"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Mail" Label="Product reviews"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Mail" Label="Contact information"/>
    </CommandBar>
    <Frame Name="MyFrame" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

**English (collapsed)**

[image]

**English (expanded)**

[image]

**French (collapsed)**

[image]

**French (expanded)**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way than the default to handle CommandBar items that have long text.

It's not better practice to make too long content for `CommandBar`, If you do want to make long content, you could set the [`DefaultLabelPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.defaultlabelposition?view=winrt-19041) as right.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CommandBar Grid.Row="0" DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <Button 
            Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" 
            Name="BackButton" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Click="Back_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>

        <AppBarButton Icon="Mail" Label="Information sur le produit" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Mail" Label="Avis sur les produits"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Mail" Label="Informations de contact"/>
    </CommandBar>
    <Frame Name="MyFrame" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```